# How to Create Datatable Columns With DataType From Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, types, datatable

How to create new DataTable with column DataType from 2D Array?
This is My Code:

```
DataTable dtColorList = new DataTable;

string[,] values = new string[,] { {"ID","int"}, {"Name","string"}, {"ColorID","int16"} };
AddDataTableColWithType(dtColorList, values);

public static void AddDataTableColWithType(DataTable dtName, string[,] colNameAndType)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colNameAndType.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            dtName.Columns.Add(colName[i,0],typeof(Type.GetType(colType[i,1])));

        }
    }
```

ERROR on Type.GetType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple solution: The basic idea is using mapping

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> PrimitiveTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>
      {
         {"int",typeof(int)},
         {"string",typeof(string)}
      };

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dtColorList = new DataTable();

        string[,] values = new string[,] { { "ID", "int" }, { "Name", "string" } };
        AddDataTableColWithType(dtColorList, values);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void AddDataTableColWithType(DataTable dtName, string[,] colNameAndType)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < colNameAndType.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            dtName.Columns.Add(colNameAndType[i, 0], PrimitiveTypes[colNameAndType[i, 1]]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very Nice, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write full name of a `Type` than you can find it using `GetType` method. If you want to get `int32` type you will have to specify like this `System.Int32`

```
string[,] values = new string[,] { { "ID", "System.Int32" }, { "Name", "System.String" }, { "ColorID", "System.Int16" } };
```